# Taking Hexidecimal Byte Array Value and Converting it to Decimal (BLE Scale Data)

Tags: java, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have code where I was able to receive data from a Bluetooth Low Energy Scale.

The form of the data being received is in a 32 Byte array.

For example when I stand on the scale, it will send out:

00 00 00 00 02 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Where the weight data is on bytes 5 and 6. If you convert the hex values of bytes 5 and 6, in that example is '0202' it becomes 514 in decimal.

Multiply that 0.1 and you get 51.4kg which is the weight of the person.

My question is, how do I take that hex byte array value in byte 5 & 6 and convert it into decimal?

I'm fairly new to Java programming so it would be amazing if I could get some sample code so I can understand the concepts.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the incoming data is typed as `byte[32]` and saved into an array named `ble`:

```
int weight = (ble[4] << 8) | ble[5];
```

Remember that Java arrays start with index 0, so the first element is `ble[0]`, not `ble[1]`. That's why the above code uses array elements 4 and 5 - they are actually the 5th and 6th elements of the array.