# Decode weight in data packets from wireshark with bluetooth low energy

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, reverse-engineering

I've been working doing some reverse engineering to different BLE based devices and I have a weight scale where I can't find a pattern to *find/decode/interpret* the *weight* value that I can get from the android app. I was also able to get the services and characteristics of this device but did not found a SIG standard match with the UUIDs from the bluetooth site.

I'm using an **nRF51** dongle to sniffing data packets between the android app and the weight scale and I can look the ble traffic, but there are several events during the communication that I can't really understand what's the relation and I can't be able to convert those values to readable weight in kg or pounds.

My target value is: *71.3kg* readed from the weight scale app.

Let me show you what I get from the ble sniffer.
[image: notification/indication request]
first I see that the `master` is sending notification/indication requests to the handles `0x0009(notify), 0x000c(indication)` and `0x000f(notify)` in each characteristic of one service.

Then I start to read notification/indications values mixed with write commands. At the end of the communication, I see some packets that I feel that they are the ones with the weight scale data and BMI. 
Packets number 574, 672 and 674 in the image.
[image: notifications and indications responses]

So that give us the following candidates:

```
1st. packet_number_574 = '000002c9070002
2nd. packet_number_672 = '420001000000005ed12059007f02c9011d01f101'
3rd. packet_number_674 = '42018c016b00070237057d001a01bc001d007c'
```

1st packet during the communication exchange looks more like a counter/RT/clock than a real measurement because of the data behavior, so I feel this one is not a real option.

2nd and 3rd looks more like real candidates, I have split them and convert them to decimal values and I have not found a relation, even combining bytes since this values are floating point data types. So my real question is, Am I missing something that you might see with this information? Do you know if there is a relation between this data packets and my target?

Thank you for taking your time reading me and any help could be good, thanks!

**EDIT:**

I have a python script that allows me to check the services and their characteristics hierarchy and some useful data like properties, their handles and descriptors.

```
Service 'fff0' (0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb):
    Characteristic 'fff1' (0000fff1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb):
              Handle: 8 (8)
            Readable: False
          Pro+perties: WRITE NOTIFY 
          Descriptor: Descriptor <Client Characteristic Configuration> (handle 0x9; uuid 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Characteristic 'fff2' (0000fff2-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb):
              Handle: 11 (b)
            Readable: False
          Properties: WRITE NO RESPONSE INDICATE 
          Descriptor: Descriptor <Client Characteristic Configuration> (handle 0xc; uuid 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Characteristic 'fff3' (0000fff3-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb):
              Handle: 14 (e)
            Readable: False
          Properties: NOTIFY 
          Descriptor: Descriptor <Client Characteristic Configuration> (handle 0xf; uuid 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
```

This are the characteristics related to the notifications and indications that I see in wireshark. I think the packet number **574** (which characteristics has only a notifiy property) is more important than I think.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have documentation about the hardware, so my real tools are the sniffer and the python scripts I used to get the services, characteristics, handles, etc.

Comment: can you share the python script ?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by myself.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40353779/taking-hexidecimal-byte-array-value-and-converting-it-to-decimal-ble-scale-data) gives me the idea to take the values (2 bytes) and multiply them by 0.1, that way I could get the weight.

In bytes I could look for my target value without decimals `713`, which is in hex = `0x02c9`

If we look at the packet number **574**: 
`000002c9070002` and split it `00:00:02:c9:07:00:02`

I could see that 2nd and 3rd bytes match with this pattern!

The only thing required to do is to group this bytes and multiply the decimal value `713 x 0.1 = 71.3`. I made different tests and found that this pattern is constant so I feel is accurate for my solution. Hope this could help someone in the future.