# Getting Byte Array From BLE (weight Scale ) Device But Could Not Interpret The Value From It E.g. Weight

Tags: angular, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth

I'm getting these buffer array in the console from this BLE device
[outputImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9rSy.png)

"12 11 FF 3E C0 13 00 03 FF 0A 03 05 00 00 05 07 53"

I'm able to connect device and read the this notifiable characteristic Don't know how to convert them to get the value weight.
Note: I'm not aware of manufactures Byte Structure that's why it's causing me trouble to find out which byte is for which purpose.

I tired with Web Bluetooth package from angular here is the code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BluetoothServiceService {
  private device: BluetoothDevice;
  private characteristic: BluetoothRemoteGATTCharacteristic;
  private  timer:any;
  constructor() { }

  async connectToDevice(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      // Request Bluetooth device
      this.device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
        // filters: [{ services: ['0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'] }],
         optionalServices: ['0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'],
        acceptAllDevices: true
      });
     console.log(this.device.name);
     console.log(this.device.id);
     console.log(this.device.gatt);
      // Connect to the device
      const server = await this.device.gatt.connect();

      // Get the primary service
      const service = await server.getPrimaryService('0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb');
      console.log('inside blue3');
      // Get the characteristic you want to read data from
      this.characteristic = await service.getCharacteristic('0000fff1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb');
      console.log( 'inside blue4');
      // Start receiving data
      await this.characteristic.startNotifications();
      console.log('inside blue5');

      // Handle incoming data
      this.characteristic.addEventListener('characteristicvaluechanged', this.handleData);
      this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
        // Clear the event listener after 5 seconds
        this.characteristic.removeEventListener('characteristicvaluechanged', this.handleData);
      }, 5000);
      console.log('inside blue6');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Bluetooth connection error:', error);
    }
  }

  private handleData(event: Event) {
    const value = (event.target as BluetoothRemoteGATTCharacteristic).value;
    // Process the received data here
    console.log(value);
    const dataView = new DataView(value.buffer);
    const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(value.byteLength);
    for (let i = 0; i < value.byteLength; i++) {
      uint8Array[i] = dataView.getUint8(i);
    }
    // Process the Uint8Array or any other data format based on your characteristic value structure
    const stringValue = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, uint8Array);
    console.log('string value',stringValue);
    // Example: Extracting individual values
    const firstValue = uint8Array[0];
    console.log(firstValue);
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
    // return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a custom format. It looks like they're squatting on currently unassigned 16-bit UUIDs (FFF0 and FFF1). You're not supposed to do that, but some folks do. (This particular pair I believe is in some TI sample code.) It doesn't look like the standard Weight Scale Service, and it doesn't look like this other custom format: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62143083/decode-weight-in-data-packets-from-wireshark-with-bluetooth-low-energy. Unless you have docs, this looks like reverse engineering. Put known weights on the scale and see what the output is. Decode from there.